# Show last 5 records in sql without using desc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5
    CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(Pout AS time), 100) AS 'OUT',
    CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(pIn AS time), 100) AS 'IN',
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(varchar(5), Pout, 108), CONVERT(varchar(5), pIn, 108)) AS [Total Used]
FROM 
    loginfo
WHERE 
    empid = 1001
    AND CONVERT(date, pDate) = '28/Nov/2016 2:45:00 PM'
    AND pOut IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    pOut
```

This query is working fine, but I don't want to show top 5 records, I need to show recent 5 records, I mean last 5 records, but I cannot to `ORDER BY pout DESC`, because I want to show report in correct format, but I need to show only last 5 records of my transaction without using descending order

Example if I have records 10 transaction, I want to show only last 5 records in correct format

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't want `desc`?

Comment: Are you saying, you will use `Order by` but not `desc` (͠◉_◉᷅ )

Comment: Now I see. Do desc in a derived table, then asc its result.

Comment: because i want to show in report ascending order ,out showing in time,who punched first,,so i want to show his first punch in as first record..

Comment: In that case, enclose the WORKING select into a new outer one that selects from the result of the inner and re-orders in the way you want to present in your report.

Comment: You NEED to use DESC to choose the rows correctly. Then you need some other order for presentation. You appear to be assuming only one order is possible. That isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
          CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(Pout AS time), 100) AS [OUT],
          CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(pIn AS time), 100) AS [IN],
          DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(varchar(5), Pout, 108),     
          CONVERT(varchar(5), pIn, 108)) AS [Total Used],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pOut DESC) as rnk
    FROM loginfo
    WHERE empid = 1001
      AND CONVERT(date, pDate) = '28/Nov/2016 2:45:00 PM'
      AND pOut IS NOT NULL) p
WHERE p.rnk <= 5
ORDER BY What_Ever_You_Want
```

Or, alternatively , use a derived table :

```
SELECT * FROM (Your Current Query)
ORDER BY pOut ;
```

Comment: sir,,it seems working..i wlill check again and confirm ..thanks

Comment: nb: it uses DESC in the over clause

Comment: @Used_By_Already It should use DESC in the over clause. He wanted the 5 latest records ordered by DESC, but to show them ordered by ASC .

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER` but there also you have to use a `DESC` with it.

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(Pout AS time), 100) AS 'OUT',
  CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(pIn AS time), 100) AS 'IN',
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(varchar(5), Pout, 108), CONVERT(varchar(5), pIn, 108)) AS [Total Used],
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pOut DESC) AS RN
  FROM loginfo
  WHERE empid = 1001
  AND CONVERT(date, pDate) = '28/Nov/2016 2:45:00 PM'
  AND pOut IS NOT NULL
) SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE RN BETWEEN 1 AND 5
ORDER BY OUT
```

Comment: I don't see how this will work. Where are you using the `ROW_NUMBER()` column ?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally erased it while copy and paste from notepad :). Updated now.